# When should I use the Url::fromRoute method instead of "new Url"

Tags: uri

I'm finding that these two PHP snippets yield the same result:

```
$arr['query']['confirm'] = 'y';
$text = t('Click here.');
$url = new Url('my_route.import', [], $arr); // Three arguments.
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl($text, $url)->toString();
```

and

```
$arr['confirm'] = 'y'; // No "query" key.
$text = t('Click here.');
$url = Url::fromRoute('my_route.import', $arr); // Two arguments.
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl($text, $url)->toString();
```

Is there any reason to prefer one approach over the other?  Which is the more typical approach?  Is there some general PHP rule of thumb that might apply, such as... always use a method on the class instead of instantiating an object with "new" whenever possible?

Comment: Not really sure if I agree with that statement.  The `Url::__construct` method is thin; it just sets a few protected variables.  The `Url::fromRoute` method essentially just invokes the constructor to return a new `Url` object.

Comment: Ok, I removed it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3A__construct/8.7.x) for the Url class:

> In most cases, use Url::fromRoute() or Url::fromUri() rather than
>   constructing Url objects directly in order to avoid ambiguity and make
>   your code more self-documenting.

So, generating a new **Url** object from a static method is preferred.

Comment: This is part of the factory vs constructor arguments in the OO world.  Using the factory is more in line with the "program to the API and not the implementation" line of thought.